# Mysql_query rows that have value different from some other values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following **mysql query**

> $query = "SELECT
>   id
>   FROM users WHERE...

and what I want is something like this

> $query = "SELECT
>   id
>   FROM users WHERE id is different from 1,2,4,5,6,7...

Is this possible? If so, how? Thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

See [12.3.2. Comparison Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html) in the manual.

Your choice would likely be [`NOT IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in):

```
WHERE id NOT IN (1,2,4,5,7)
```